# How to check websites offline for media queries?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

How to check websites offline for media queries?

The clear explanation is below for the question:

1. I am working on 1024 x 768 resolution only.
2. I need to check the website designs more than the above mentioned resolution offline.
3. Is there any offline software or tool to check all the smart devices dimensions, and laptop, bigger screens etc.

Thanks in advance for those who give solution for me.

Comment: chrome has the functionality inbuilt in the dev kit tools

Comment: @ryanc1256 Thank you. Your comment is useful and related to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Ripple Emulator for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ripple-emulator-beta/geelfhphabnejjhdalkjhgipohgpdnoc?hl=en).

**EDIT:**
To check it for resolution higher than 1024 x 768, first set your screen resolution higher than that. Then open Firefox. Do Ctrl+Shift+M and set whatever resolution that you want.

Comment: Thank you. This emulator is for mobile, smartphone versions. Also I need it for big screens which are bigger than 1024 x 768 resolution. Can you please?.

Comment: @StylerKishore Please see the edit in the answer above.

Comment: Ok. it's working. But I can't view the footer section even I increased the height from the dimension. Could you pls tell me to check in Chrome like this?.

Comment: @StylerKishore Please post a demo in jsFiddle/JSbin so I can check it myself.

Comment: It's too large file. Ok fine. Let me try. Thank You.

Comment: I am able to view the footer also now.